# How to create a unity event to determine distance between objects, and do something when distance is small enough?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the EventManager and according Events to calculate the distance between objects, and to do something when enough objects are close to the target.

I watched video's on YouTube and searched for examples on Google, but I couldn't find something that looks like what I want. Of course I also watched the explanation videos of Events in general, but I just don't get it. They are all English, which is not my native language, this makes it difficult to understand. So, also sorry for any grammar mistakes. They often talk so fast. So please don't think I'm lazy, I have searched for hours but I just don't get it.

I have one target object, and several enemy objects. This enemy objects have the tag 'Enemy'. The target object can move. I made a coroutine, so when the target moves, the enemies follow, until a distance of 0.5. But from the moment that they reached the distance of 0.5, the enemies won't move anymore. Instead they should also follow the target when they already reached their target position. So to prevent this, I changed the `while(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > 0.5f)` in `while 1 > 0`, (so just always) and I deleted the part of the code that was about 'after the while loop'. But this is probably not the right way.

So, in short, I want to make an Event that keeps track of when enemies reaches or loses their target position. When three enemies are on their target position, I want to make them blue.

Could anyone show me how I can do this? I don't get it now, but when I see how it works I can use this for more events in the game.

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: So, is your difficulty with events, or is it with the `while` loop? For events, use the `UnityEvent` class instead of default c# events + `Observable` programming pattern, to watch the variable and do something when it's value reaches in our out of a certain value or range. As far as I could understand your troubles, the `Observable` pattern should also solve the `while` loop problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use trigger collider, just make it bigger then your target object, then do all you want about enemies in methods OnTriggetEnter, OnTriggerStay

Answer (score 0):

As an another technique you can use raycasts. Raycasts will provide you more performance than colliders.

You can locate your raycasts in your target position, in case your raycast hit the enemy then make them blue. For Example;

public LayerMask enemyLayer;
bool isTouch = false;

```
public bool isTouched(){
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position,-Vector3.up,1f,enemyLayer)) {
            isTouch = true;
            return isTouch ;
        }
        return !isTouch ;
    }
```